# Vuejs undefined property error but it is defined

Tags: javascript, templates, vue.js, undefined, vuex

I have a simple Vue component that simply list server connection data:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="page-header">
          <h2 class="title">Data</h2>
        </div>
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <table class="table">
          <tr>
            <td>Server</td>
            <td><strong>{{config.servers}}</strong></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Port</td>
            <td><strong>{{config.port}}</strong></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td><strong>{{config.description}}</strong></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Protocol</td>
            <td :class="{'text-success': isHttps}">
              <i v-if="isHttps" class="fa fa-lock"></i>
              <strong>{{config.scheme}}</strong>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'Application',

  data () {
    return {
      config: {
        scheme: '',
        servers: '',
        port: '',
        description: ''
      }
    }
  },

  computed: {
    ...mapState(['server']),

    isHttps: () => this.config.scheme === 'https'
  },

  mounted () {
    const matched = this.server.match(/(https?):\/\/(.+):(\d+)/)
    this.config = {
      scheme: matched[1],
      servers: matched[2],
      port: matched[3],
      description: window.location.hostname.split('.')[0] || 'Server'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The `server` from Vuex is already defined and done when this component is mounted, and if I try to `console.log(this.server)`, it shows the correct URL. The thing is, my computed property `isHttps` throws the following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render function: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'scheme' of undefined"

found in

---> <Application> at src/pages/Aplicativo.vue
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root>
```

I've already tried to change `config` to something else, like `configuration` or `details`, and even changed `mounted` to `created`, but the error keeps popping up and my template is *not rendered at all*.

Firstly I began making `config` a computed property, but the error was already making its way to my console. By the way, using store as a computed property like this also throws an error saying my `$store` is undefined:

```
server: () => this.$store.state.server
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an arrow function for your `isHttps` computed. In that context, `this` refers to `window` not the Vue instance, so you will get a `cannot read property of undefined` message, the correct ES2015 syntax is:

```
isHttps() { 
  return this.config.scheme === 'https'
}
```

That is also the same problem with `server: () => this.$store.state.server` which should be:

```
server() { 
  return this.$store.state.server
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!